# Is there a precedent for scripting extensions within Javascript application?

Tags: javascript, scripting, ide, electron

The ability to run user-scripts is a powerful extension for power users, as provided in VBA (for MS Office) or EASE Scripting (for Eclipse).

Is there a precedent for providing such a capability within the JS domain?

1. Yes, I know a JS app is scripted, but I'm looking at it from a user perspective:
   a user wishes to extend a JS application (single page app, electron app, NodeJS service) with some custom JS script, potentially accessing the app's object model.
2. Yes, a JS app could be extended through the inclusion of additional packages at run-time, but the previous examples include an IDE-type environment in which the scripting is conducted.

Can anybody point to an example of this?  Clearly security is an issue (since, for example) the app may have privileged file access that user scripts shouldn't)

Note 1: I'm aware that technically it's provided in VS Code [1], but that's already an IDE, so doesn't seem like a good example.

Note 2: I've now found a component that provides IDE functionality [2], though haven't found an example of it being used for an JS app's "macro editor".

[1]. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/overview

[2]. https://ace.c9.io/

Comment: Best example I can think of is the Office 365 web apps, which can be extended via [Office Add-ins](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/office).

Comment: @JoeClay - yes. An alternate is VS Code: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/overview 
Significantly it provides the IDE element. Well, it is an IDE!

Comment: Ah, can't believe I forgot that one :p

Answer (score 1):

One way I can think of is using eval(). In your case you can ignore the usual eval is evil talk given that you want to give users access to your application.

Example in electron:

Renderer process----

```js
const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron');

 var _o = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
_o[0].onclick = function(evt) {
  var js_raw = document.getElementById('js_raw').value;
  ipcRenderer.send('execute_user_js', js_raw);
}
```

```html
<input id="js_raw"></input><button>Execute User JS</button>
```

Main process----

```js
const {ipcMain} = require('electron');

//public methods for users to call
var my_obj_vusers = {
 public: function() {console.log("i am public function");}
};

ipcMain.on('execute_user_js', (event, arg) => {
   //note: in production I would ensure that the user code does not include code patterns I do not want the user to execute (eg with regex)
   eval(arg); //user can also access public objects eg. my_obj_vusers.public()
   return;
})
```

Comment: Thanks for that @11AND2.  That's a way of firing up the JS, but I'm interested in the higher level architecture, and technologies (components) that would provide a JS IDE experience.